Is it possible to exclude specific outputs in github actions contexts?
I'm capturing a jobs step context data for log aggregation like this:
- id: 'auth'
  name: 'auth'
  uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v0.4.0'
  with:
    token_format: 'access_token'
    workload_identity_provider: 'xxxxx'
    service_account: xxxxx

- name: a step that fails
  id: test
  run: |
    fail

- name: Ship Log Errors
  if: always() && job.status == 'failure'
  env:
    # How do I exclude the access_token output?
    STEPS_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(steps) }}

  run: |
    command-to-ship-logs $STEPS_CONTEXT

The problem is $STEPS_CONTEXT includes an output from the auth step access_token that has sensitive info.
Is there a way to just exclude or clobber a previous steps outputs so they don't appear in the steps context? Are contexts immutable? I'd like to just be able to do something like this steps.auth.outputs.access_token = "****" is that possible somehow?

You might be able to mask it with a workflow command.

That might be good enough. Could you provide an example as an answer? An example showing how to ref the value of that output in the steps context in the echo statement?
